# User login directly into LXC container

Tags: lxc, administration

Is it possible to setup host system so that some users will be immediately in corresponding LXC container after logging in?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but I would instead suggest providing the Linux container with its own IP address or port instead. This would be more secure and scale better.

If you still want to stay the course of logging into the host first, here is a method,

1. Setup SSH Server on the Linux Container
2. On host as that user, generate private key and public key
3. Create same user and place public key on Linux Container
4. Modify user's profile to automatically execute SSH into LXC